# requirejs with revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, module, requirejs

```
define(['controls'], function (controls) 
{
    var something = 10;
    var someFunction = function(someValue)
    {
        something = someValue;
    }; 
    return {
        smth:someFunction,
        smvl:something
    };
});
```

I simplified for the sake of solving the issue. I am using requirejs.

```
require(['player', 'world', 'controls'], function (player, world, controls) 
{
    console.log(player.smvl);
    player.smth(50);
    console.log(player.smvl);
});
```

So the first part of code is *player.js*. In my main module, first console log displays "10", then I use public function from *player.js* to change `something` value.

But when I use console log again, it still displays 10. So why isn't it changing? I must be doing something completely wrong, and missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

player.js

```
define('player', function () {
    var player = function () {
        this.smvl = 10;
        return {
            smth: function (someValue) {
                this.smvl = someValue;
            },
            smvl: this.smvl
        }
    }
    return new player();
});
```

calling code

```
require(['player'], function (player) {
    console.log(player.smvl); //10
    player.smth(50);
    console.log(player.smvl); //50
    console.log(window.smvl); //undefined
});
```